# How to formulate a mongoose query in which (Field A * Field B + Field C) < f?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I need to obtain a list of all online drivers in which their computed fares are less than a fixed value. In a nutshell, what is the best way to formulate the mongoose query in which:

(RATE * DISTANCE) + BASE_FARE < max_fare

where RATE and BASE_FARE are fields in the same queried Driver schema, 'max_fare' is a constant, and DISTANCE is the field obtained from the previous $geoNear stage in the aggregate pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured. Basically I need to use $expr. My final aggregation pipeline stage looks like this:

```
pipeline.push({
    $match:{$expr:{$and:[{$gte:[{$add:[{$multiply:["$ratePerKM",{$add:[{$divide:["$distance",1000]},query.maxKM.$gte]}]},"$baseFee"]},query.fareMin]},
                         {$lte:[{$add:[{$multiply:["$ratePerKM",{$add:[{$divide:["$distance",1000]},query.maxKM.$gte]}]},"$baseFee"]},query.fareMax]}]}}});
```

which filters the computed fares so that they fall between a minimum and a maximum.